# ¿Como mostrar un error si las contraseñas no coinciden?

Tags: php, html, html5, web, validación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola, quisiera saber como puedo enviar un mensaje de error a través de PHP, si al presionar el botón registrate los campos contraseña y confirmar contraseña no coinciden. Esto es lo que tengo hasta el momento:

```html
<div class="Registro animated2 fadeIn-1">
   <form class="Formulario" action="../php/Registro.php"                method="POST">
    <div class="Container">
     <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" name="usuario" class="usuario"                 placeholder="Usuario" autocomplete="off" required />
     </div>
     <div class="input-group">
      <input type="email" name="correo" class="correo"                   placeholder="Correo" autocomplete="off" required />
     </div>
     <div class="input-group">
      <input type="password" name="pass" class="password"               id="pass" placeholder="Contraseña" autocomplete="off"             required />
     </div>
     <div class="input-group">
      <span id="change" class="eye"></span><input                       type="password" name="pass2" class="password"                     id="pass2" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Confirmar               contraseña" required />
     </div>
     <input type="submit" class="btn-submit"                           value="Regístrate" />
    </div>
   </form>
   <div class="Texto1">
    ¿Ya tienes cuenta?
   </div>
   <div class="Texto2">
    <a href="Login.html">Iniciar Sesión</a>
   </div>
</div>

Este es mi codigo PHP que se encuentra en otro archivo:
<?php
 include("Conexion.php");
 $usu = $_POST["usuario"];
 $cor = $_POST["correo"];
 $pass = $_POST["pass"];
 $pass2 = $_POST["pass2"];
 $passEncriptado;

 if ($pass==$pass2) {
  $passEncriptado = md5($pass);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES(null,'".$usu."','".$cor."','".$passEncriptado."')";
  $respuesta = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error");
  mysql_close($respuesta);
  header("location: ../html/Index.html");
 }
?>
```

Comment: Creo que antes de enviar la información al servidor seria mejor realizar esta comprobación primero en el navegador con javascript. Igualmente para contestar a tu pregunta seria necesario saber mas cosas como por ejemplo como envias el formulario. Como un envió normal del formulario? o mediante ajax?

Comment: Lo envio de forma normal

Comment: ¿Y como se podría realizar esta comprobación a través de javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Para mostrar mensajes de error, simplemente debes trabajar con el identificador de cada `input` de tu formulario, es decir, el atributo `name`.

Realmente si quieres comprobar que las dos contraseñas no son idénticas lo podrías hacer así:

```
if ($_POST['pass'] != $_POST['pass2']) {
   echo 'La contraseña de verificación no coincide.';
} else {
   //Obtienes los datos de tus inputs.
}
```

En mi ejemplo te he puesto mas alertas en `PHP` para explicar mejor su funcionamiento, si quieres obtener dichos mensajes, simplemente elimina el atributo `required` de tus `inputs`.

### Un posible ejemplo

**Formulario**

```
<form action="registro.php" method="POST">  
    <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario" autocomplete="off" required />                  
    <input type="email" name="correo" placeholder="Correo" autocomplete="off" required />                   
    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Contraseña" autocomplete="off" required />                  
    <input  type="password" name="pass2" placeholder="Confirmar contraseña" autocomplete="off" required />
    <input type="submit" class="btn-submit" value="Regístrate" />               
</form>
```

**registro.php**

```
<?php

//Reseteo variables.
$msg = $usuario = $correo = $pass = NULL;

//Si esta definido el formulario y no es NULL.
if (isset($_POST)) {        

    //Comprobacion campos vacios.
    if (empty($_POST['usuario'])) {
        $msg = 'El usuario es obligatorio.';
    } elseif (empty($_POST['correo'])) {
        $msg = 'El correo electrónico es obligatorio.';
    } elseif (!filter_var($_POST['correo'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $msg = 'El correo electrónico no es valido.';
    } elseif (empty($_POST['pass'])) {
        $msg = 'La contraseña es obligatorio.';
    } elseif (empty($_POST['pass2'])) {
        $msg = 'Debes verificar la contraseña.';
    } elseif ($_POST['pass'] != $_POST['pass2']) {
        $msg = 'La contraseña de verificación no coincide.';
    } else { //Todo correcto obtienes los datos desde formulario.
        //Obtenemos datos.
        $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
        $correo = $_POST['correo'];
        //password_hash — Crea un hash de contraseña.
        //BCRYPT, tendrá siempre 60 caracteres, importante que en la Base de datos pueda obtener 60 caracteres.
        $pass = password_hash($_POST['pass'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);     
    }

    //Los datos son verdadero, continuas con tu insert.
    if ($usuario && $correo && $pass) {
        echo "Todo correcto, insertar datos a la Base de Datos.";
    } 

}
//Mensaje de alerta.
echo $msg;

?>
```

> **Advertencia:** La extensión `mysql*` fue declarada obsoleta en `PHP 5.5.0` y eliminada en `PHP 7.0.0.` En su lugar debería utilzarse las extensiones `MySQLi` o `PDO_MySQL`.

[¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

**Debes utilizar mysqli, no mysql**

```
<div class="Registro animated2 fadeIn-1">
<?php if (isset($_COOKIE["incorrectPassw"])): ?>
    Error! Las contraseñas no coinciden.
<?php setcookie("incorrectPassw",time()-1600);
<?php endif; ?>
            <form class="Formulario" action="../php/Registro.php"                method="POST">
                <div class="Container">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" name="usuario" class="usuario"                 placeholder="Usuario" autocomplete="off" required />
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="email" name="correo" class="correo"                   placeholder="Correo" autocomplete="off" required />
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="password" name="pass" class="password"               id="pass" placeholder="Contraseña" autocomplete="off"             required />
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span id="change" class="eye"></span><input                       type="password" name="pass2" class="password"                     id="pass2" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Confirmar               contraseña" required />
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn-submit"                           value="Regístrate" />
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="Texto1">
                ¿Ya tienes cuenta?
            </div>
            <div class="Texto2">
                <a href="Login.html">Iniciar Sesión</a>
            </div>
</div>

Este es el codigo PHP que se encuentra en otro archivo:
<?php
    include("Conexion.php");
    $usu = $_POST["usuario"];
    $cor = $_POST["correo"];
    $pass = $_POST["pass"];
    $pass2 = $_POST["pass2"];
    $passEncriptado;

    if ($pass==$pass2) {
        $passEncriptado = md5($pass);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES(null,'".$usu."','".$cor."','".$passEncriptado."')";
        $respuesta = mysqli_query($sql) or die ("Error");
        mysqli_close($respuesta);
        header("location: ../html/Index.html");
    }else{
       setcookie("incorrectPassw","true");
      header("location: login.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Amigo no me funciona, por favor ayudame, que se supone que deberia mostrar

Comment: Haaa! Disculpa, lo que debe pasar es que si las contraseñas no coinciden, debe regresar nuevamente al login... Eso me faltó poner en el código, y ahí se ejecuta la condición, en caso que se haya establecido la cookie debería aparecer un texto plano sobre el documento que diga qur hay un error con respecto a las contraseñas (eso lo puedes utilizar como tú lo desees).